# starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory ---- executor failed running [/bin/sh -c

Tags: linux, bash, docker, devops

I am trying to build my dockerfile as shown thus:

```
ARG IMG_TAG=latest

# Compile the gaiad binary
FROM golang:1.18-alpine AS gaiad-builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY go.mod go.sum* ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
ENV PACKAGES curl make git libc-dev bash gcc linux-headers eudev-dev python3
RUN apk add --no-cache $PACKAGES
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 make install

# Add to a distroless container
FROM distroless.dev/static:$IMG_TAG
ARG IMG_TAG
COPY --from=gaiad-builder /go/bin/gaiad /bin

RUN gaiad init Edima 
    # && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosmos/mainnet/master/genesis/genesis.cosmoshub-4.json.gz \
    # && gzip -d genesis.cosmoshub-4.json.gz \
    # && mv genesis.cosmoshub-4.json ~/.gaia/config/genesis.json 

# RUN gaiad start --x-crisis-skip-assert-invariants

EXPOSE 26656 26657 1317 9090
USER 0

ENTRYPOINT ["gaiad", "start"]
```

But I am getting an error when I run `docker build .`, the error is shown:

```
 => ERROR [stage-1 3/3] RUN /bin/gaiad init Edima                                                                                                                               0.4s
------
 > [stage-1 3/3] RUN /bin/gaiad init Edima:
#16 0.432 container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /bin/gaiad init Edima]: exit code: 1
```

COuld anyone help with how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "distroless" image usually only contains a very minimal set of libraries and configuration files.  It won't contain, for example, a shell, so you can't run shell commands.

The approach I'm used to seeing for a distroless (or similarly `scratch`) based image is to do all of the necessary setup in previous steps, then `COPY` content into the final image.  Whatever work `gaiad init` does, if it can reasonably be built into an image, it should be done in a previous stage, and then its result `COPY`ed in.

```bash
FROM golang:1.18-alpine AS gaiad-builder
...
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 make install

# still in the build stage
ENV HOME=/
RUN /go/bin/gaiad init Enima

FROM distroless.dev/static:$IMG_TAG
# (don't RUN anything in the final "FROM distroless" build stage)
COPY --from=gaiad-builder /go/bin/gaiad /gaiad
COPY --from=gaiad-builder /.gaiad/ /.gaiad/
ENV HOME=/
ENTRYPOINT ["/gaiad", "start"]
```

If that's not an option, then (like `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`) the `RUN` directive comes in two forms.  If you `RUN some command` then Docker automatically runs that via a shell; but the distroless image doesn't have a shell, which leads to the `/bin/sh: no such file or directory` error.  You can also pass a JSON array to `RUN`, which doesn't invoke a shell, but also requires you to manually split up words yourself, and can't do things like environment-variable substitution:

```bash
RUN ["gaiad", "init", "Edima"]
```

If *that's* not an option, then a distroless image won't work for you.  The comments hint at wanting to download more files and run a sequence of commands in the final image.  Since you build the application using an Alpine-based image, you can change the final image to match

```bash
FROM alpine
COPY --from=gaiad-builder /go/bin/gaiad /bin/
# which includes a POSIX /bin/sh, so this now works again
RUN gaiad init Enima
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I didn't know this about the distroless container. Anyways, it worked.

Comment: But then, the image container does not run, it crashes and I suspect the endpoint